# Adjoint Functors Operating On Natural Transformations

Tags: category-theory, adjoint-functors

Suppose we have a natural transformation $\alpha$ from functor $L: \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ to functor $L': \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$. Suppose $R: \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is the right adjoint of $L$. Suppose $R': \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is the right adjoint of $L'.$ Then is it possible to use $\alpha$ to somehow construct a natural transformation from $R'$ to $R$ ? If so how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have, for any $x\in \mathbb D$, the map $\bar\alpha_x: R'x\to RLR'x\to RL'R'x\to Rx $
given by composing the unit of the $(L,R)$ adjunction at $R'x$ with $R(\alpha_{R'X})$ and $R$ of the counit of the $(L',R')$ adjunction at $x$. It is straightforward to check that the $\bar\alpha_x$ assemble into a natural transformation $R'\to R$, called the *mate* of $\alpha$ in the literature.

In fact, the mate is the key ingredient needed to construct an identity-on-objects equivalence, contravariant on 1-morphisms and 2-morphisms, between the 2-category of categories, left adjoint functors, and natural transformations between them, and the 2-category of categories, right adjoint functors, and natural transformations between them.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. I think I found it in the special case of right Kan extensions. I am guessing there is also a dual construction. I am guessing if $\beta$ is a natural transformation from $R'$ to $R$ then the "comate" of $\beta$ is a natural transformation from $L$ to $L'$ that has a component for $y \in \mathbb{C}$ that is $Ly \rightarrow LR'L'y \rightarrow LRL'y \rightarrow L'y$ made using the unit of the $(L',R')$ adjunction, followed by $L(\beta_{L'y})$, followed by usage of the counit of the $(L,R)$ adjunction.

Comment: I am also guessing that the function sending a natural transformation to it's mate is the inverse of the function sending a natural transformation to it's comate. But it would be good if you could let me know if I am on the right track, or suggest literature.

Comment: @RichardSouthwell Yep, that’s all good. Usually we just say “mate” for both. There’s a dearth of literature in 2-category theory but you can read about mates on the nLab or in the appendices of Groth’s paper “derivators, pointed derivators...” or at least one of his papers with Ponto and Shulman.

Comment: Great, thanks for the help.